# Rastering Vector Art: Photoshop vs Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector, export, pixel

I have been working in illustrator CS5 making vector art. My main focus has been different iPhone game graphics (I make them in illustrator instead of photoshop so I can scale them for all the different devices and tablets) and have been so focused on making the art and learning (at least trying to) lots of different techniques that I overlooked the saving and exporting aspects. **So I was hoping if someone would be able to help explain the best practice for rasterizing vector art.**

I'm aware of `file > save for web and devices` and because I'm doing mainly iPhone graphics, I will be saving in `PNG24`. Is that all there is to it, or are there any tricks or techniques to make the art better or clearer? Because I'm rasterizing vector art, is there anything I need to keep in mind or do when I am actually making the art?

For example, I'm not sure if it would be better to take the vector art into Photoshop as a smart object, and then save it from Photoshop as it is a pixel based programme, maybe it has more options. Is that the case?

Comment: By 'pixel art' are you referring to a particular aesthetic (typically what would be called 8-bit graphics) or are you referring to a particular file format (raster based images)?

Comment: I mean raster based images, sorry for the confusion will edit the question to make things clearer. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For many instances simply using Save for Web or Exporting from Illustrator is sufficient.

You may need to take care that you choose the right anti-aliasing option. Often Art Optimized yields the best results.

And working with the Align to Pixel Grid option turned **on** always helps keep things crisp and smooth.

I only move items to Photoshop if I want to edit the pixels. Sometimes, after exporting, there may be a few pixels which could use a minot color change to help the appearance. I'll then open the image from Illustrator with Photoshop so I can zoom in and hit a pixel or two.